# Converting EditText / TextView to String?

Tags: android, string, textview, android-edittext

Our Sample Code

```
EditText txtData = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtData);
Button btnReadSDFile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReadSDFile);
btnReadSDFile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // write on SD card file data in the text box
        try {
            //Read a file from SDCard to TextBox(EditText)
            File myFile = new File("/mnt/sdcard/config_data.med");
            FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);
            BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fIn));
            String aDataRow = "";
            String aBuffer = "";
            while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
                aBuffer += aDataRow + "\n";
            }
            txtData.setText(aBuffer);
            myReader.close();
            String s = txtData.getText().toString();
            Log.e("txtData",s);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Our Original File Content

```
Welcome
To
All
```

Our Log Result ScreenShot

[image]

Why is our content collapsing here? How do we solve it?

Comment: But you are already getting aBuffer value as string than why are you setting it into edittext and again trying to get the same value from edittext.Try to print aBuffer into Log and see what comes??

Comment: Good question. I am tried without `EditText` and using `String` and also i got the same answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be an encoding problem. Try this:

```
FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);
BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fIn, "UTF-8"));
```

Refer Different Encoding Charset
[Encoding Charset](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/Charset.html)

Comment: I got a error Message `The constructor FileInputStream(File, String) is undefined`

Comment: I edit my answer. There was a writing mistake. I'm sorry! The string is passed to InputStreamReader constructor and not to FileInputStrem constructor.

Comment: Thanks. It's a Encoding Problem.